# why the head at main doest get the node?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

im trying to insert node to the begging of link list but the value from poiter to poiter isnt passing
i wrote a note ***** where the problem accure

```
void insertTolist(list* head, list* node)
{
    list* current = head;
    list* currentPlusOne = head->next;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        if (current->data<node->data && currentPlusOne->data>node->data)
        {
            current->next = node;
            node->next = currentPlusOne;
            break;
        }
        if (current->data<node->data && currentPlusOne->next == NULL)
        {
            current->next = node;
            node->next = (list*)calloc(1, sizeof(list));
            break;
        }
        if (current->data > node->data && currentPlusOne->data >node->data)// b c 
        {
            node->next =current;
            head = node;// ***the head doesnt chanching at the main***
            break;
        }
        current = current->next;
        currentPlusOne = currentPlusOne->next;
    }
    //printlist(head);
}
```

Comment: If you're asking about what is happening in the `main` function, it would be helpful to include it!  But it's fairly clear that the problem is simply that you are modifying the local variable.  If you want to modify a variable in the caller, then the caller should pass an address.  eg, in main, you would have `list *head; ... insertToList(&head)` and the function would take a `list **`

Comment: thank you very much! you solved it .

Answer (score 1):

The function declared like

```
void insertTolist(list* head, list* node)
```

deals with a copy of the value of the pointer to the head node used as an argument. Changing the copy in this statement

```
head = node;
```

is not reflected on the value of the original pointer.

Moreover the function can invoke undefined behavior if the passed pointer is a null pointer at least due to this declaration

```
list* currentPlusOne = head->next;
```

Also this statement

```
node->next = (list*)calloc(1, sizeof(list));
```

does not make a sense.

You need either to pass the pointer to the head node to the function by reference through a pointer to it or to return from the function the pointer (possibly modified) to the head node and to assign its value to the original pointer.

If to use the first approach then the function will look enough simple.

```
void insertTolist( list **head, list *node )
{
    while ( *head != NULL && !( node->data < ( *head )->data ) )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    node->next = *head;
    *head = node;
}
```

and if in the caller the pointer `head` is declared like

```
list *head = NULL;
```

then the function is called like

```
insertTolist( &head, node );
```

where node is a pointer to the inserted node in the list.